# Why my tweet is not appearing on the timeline of the person I am following?

Tags: twitter

I have tried tweeting someone I follow couple of times.  My tweets appear on my profile but when I look at the other person's timeline, my tweet is not there. I am following him but he is not following me.

Answer (score 2):

Timeline of a person displays only those tweets made by that user. If you reply someone or make a new tweet it will be only visible in your timeline irrespective of whom you tweet to.